# Adding content with gif when javascript button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I created a JavaScript button that generates Facts (gifs),
i would love to have a share option to social media facebook for an example
below my GIF 
i have the facebook plugin I just dont know where to put it.
here is the code:

```js
  var currImage = 0;
window.onload = () => {
    const factsArr = [  
    {
    image:
    'https://media.giphy.com/media/qvpc2K9M3OVy/giphy.gif',
    },
 {
 image:'https://media.giphy.com/media/TvsLe5DV4gKCQ/giphy.gif',
 },
 {
 image:'https://media.giphy.com/media/1nkUav308CBws/giphy.gif',
 }
    ];
  document.getElementById('generate-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
      
     document.getElementById('image').setAttribute('src', factsArr[currImage].image);
      currImage++;
      if (currImage == factsArr.length)
         currImage  = 0;
    })
      
}
```

```html
<button id="generate-btn">Amazing Fact Button</button>
<img id="image"></img>
</button>
```

Comment: I think putting `document.getElementById('share-panel').style="display:block";` inside `addEventListener()` will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

simply execute the fb plugin code in a click call back. I mean on click of the share button, call the API on fb plugin to share.

Comment: Can please explain more?